# How to drop the nodes in specified positions of the layer in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I’m trying to implement a fully connected network to do a 
    classification task, while my training data contains some missing 
    values and the positions of missingness are not fixed.

For example:

```
[x1, x2, NaN, x4, x5]  [y]
[x1, x2, x3, x4, NaN]  [y]
[NaN, x2, x3, NaN, x5] [y]
```

I have tried to implement some methods to fill in the missing values 
but it will introduce bias after all.

To solve the bias problem, I’m planning to keep the missingness but 
drop the corresponding nodes that the missing values appear in the 
input layer so that the `NaNs` will not be fed into the network and cause 
errors, and the following layers of the network stay the same. I wonder 
if there are specific methods to achieve it in PyTorch, either by:

1. Drop the node in a specified position of the layer, or
2. Enable variable input size of the neural network.

However, these are just two possible solutions I can come up with, I 
would be appreciated if you could share with me other useful ways.

Comment: If you only want to feed these vectors into a Linear layer, you can just set the NaNs to zero. Think about it - a linear layer does a matrix multiplication first (where 0 is the null element, i.e. is inactive), and then adds the bias, and then adds the nonlinearity.

Comment: Yes, this totally makes sense. Thank you!